# Remove payment_address payment_method from checkout/checkout page Opencart 3.x

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

hi i need to remove payment_address payment_method from checkout/checkout page Opencart 3.x.
i donot want extension, please some body help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can activate a COD payment method and then simply hide this step with basic CSS and a bit of JS to open the final step in the default checkout.

But Opencart heavily relies on Payment_address. Payment Address has several fields that are required like country, zone and often postcode.

Removing the payment_address will break the whole system. What you can do is via simple HTML and CSS, populate the fields with default values and then hide with CSS.

for example in `catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/payment_address.twig`

```
...html
<div class="form-group required">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-payment-firstname">{{ entry_firstname }}</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<MY_DEFAULT_FIRST_NAME>" placeholder="{{ entry_firstname }}" id="input-payment-firstname" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
...
```

do this for all the fields.

then in `catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/checkout.twig` do `style="display:none'`

```html
<div class="panel panel-default" style="display:none">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">{{ text_checkout_account }}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-payment-address">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="display:none">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">{{ text_checkout_payment_address }}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-payment-address">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

> this will just hide the payment_address block but it will still be there.

and now you need to `skip` the payment address step by calling the `Continue` button via JavaScript

so in the same file `catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/checkout.twig`
after line 165

```js
$('a[href=\'#collapse-payment-address\']').trigger('click');

//add this code to trigger continue button:
$('#button-payment-address').trigger('click');
```

You might need to wrap the trigger click action with `setTimeout` becuase you might trigger the click before the form is actually loaded.

> I would also advise to do this in a CUSTOM theme folder, and not in the default opencart theme. this way you can do the modifications without touching the core file.